# Fast CSV parser with low GC load

Tags: java, performance, parsing, csv, garbage-collection

Does anybody knows a fast CSV parser which has a low impact on GC? For example SuperCsv creates too many objects(Strings) and GC is not so happy about that...

Thanks.

Comment: The kind of GC used in many JVMs propably including yours (generational GC) handles short-lived objects quite well by design. Unless you can prove there's a problem...

Comment: What exactly is "too many strings"? A csv parser just tokenizes a string, splitting it by commas or tabs or whatever. You can't create less strings than there are items in your file (unless you're streaming it).

Comment: I wrote one myself which doesn't produce any objects. Its not open source, but it can be done. If are interested in writing this yourself, I can give you some hints.

Comment: @Peter I can write it myself, just trying to not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @delnar I know and indeed it isn't that much of a problem, there are only short lived objects. With 5 threads I have around 60 minor collections per second and no major collections. However, even if this might not be an issue I do not like to have my memory bouncing up& down every 2 seconds from 10M to 100M. GC is using around 3% CPU(which means ~ 24% of a single core since I have 8 cores) and even if is not that bad it could be better

Comment: If you want so optimized - just write it by you own specs. 
With the right balance mem usage vs algorithm complexity. It's the best :)

Those general purpose libs are not always aligned with our needs ..

Comment: My specs where very tight so I had to write it myself. The whole application full GCs once per day over night (no minor GCs).  I don't know of any parsing library which was designed with this requirement in mind. ;)

Comment: @deian true but It always worth asking around...

Comment: @peter based on current feedback I will probably end up writing the parser myself :) Any suggestions are welcomed - dead ends, hints, etc - you can send me messages on the email address on the account. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating strings, I suggest you use a fixed length char[] to read content from the file say 10K characters at a time. Decide the size of the char[] based on what's the most likely maximum characters in a line. Then loop through the char[] and look for comma,. As soon as you found a comma, save the position in a int[]. So, int[0] says the first comma position, int[1] the second comma and so on. Reuse the int[] for each line.

This way you never declare any variable for each line. Thus no GC overhead. All you need to do is read value of each field from the large char[] using the positions stored in int[] and make sense out of it.

Comment: thanks, I know how I would implemented but before I will start I wanted to see if there are already CVS parsers out-there providing what I need...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/titorenko/quick-csv-streamer, it creates minimum amount of garbage.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.